# IF Statement with VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to get a value from the ADD Taxable which is column 10 in the Check (sheet). I only want the value from column 10 if the Earn Type on Timecard (Sheet) has BONUS in it. I'm using the TC Ref for the VLOOKUP.

All my values are 0 and I have 92 records on the Timecard (Sheet) that have BONUS in the Earn Type column. The formula I tried to make doesn't work

Timecard (Sheet)

```
TC Ref, Check Date, Work Date, Pay Start, Pay End, Trade, Union, Pay Rate, Hours, Earn Type, Emp ID, Job ID
```

Check (Sheet)

```
TC Ref, Check Date, Check Number, Check Amount, Emp ID, RE Hours, RE Earnings, OT-PT Hours, OT-PT Earnings, ADD Taxable
```

Attempted formula:

```
=IF(Table_timecard[@[Earn Type]]="BONUS",VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_check,10,FALSE),0)
```

Working formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_timecard,10,FALSE)="BONUS",VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_check,10,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is your formula not working as expected? If so, give an example of what it is returning and what you expect it to return instead.

Comment: yes sorry it isn't working all my values are 0. I have 92 records on the Timecard (Sheet) that have BONUS in the Earn Type column. The formula I tried to make doesn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you reworded to include a question. First step would be to break out the vlookup into a separate column and see what it is returning, if anything. Is the lookup table sorted?

Comment: the lookup table is sort ascending by the TC Ref and it's the first column. When I do

Comment: VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_check,10,FALSE) I get all the values, but I'm looking just for the ones that are designated as BONUS

Comment: the sheets have tables on them I didn't know if it made a difference, sorry

Comment: If you're searching in a table, you need to use table notation. Something like `=IF(Table_timecard[[Earn Type]]="BONUS",VLOOKUP(Table_timecard[[TC Ref]],(Table_check[#data],10,0),0)`

Comment: I tried different variations, would it be possible to send you the sheet so you can see what I have.

Comment: Are you sure "BONUS" doesn't have any leading or trailing spaces?  That has bitten me more than once.

Comment: yes there are no leading or trailing spaces I made sure once it wasn't working.

Comment: I think I finally figured it out. It appears to be working properly with the one just made with the help from Raystafarian thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Raysafarian for all the great guidance I was able to come up with a working formula.

```
  =IF(Table_timecard[[Earn Type]]="BONUS",VLOOKUP(Table_timecard[[TC Ref]],(Table_check[#data],10,0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching a *table* right?

```
=IF(Table_timecard[[Earn Type]]="BONUS",VLOOKUP(Table_timecard[[TC Ref]],(Table_check[#data],10,0),0)
```

That should work. You need to specify that the lookup_array is a table, search the whole thing and then pick your column to return.

If you aren't searching in a table, you need to specify a cell range, which could be `A1:M99` or if you have a **named range** and you name `A1:M99` "Table_Check", it would also work.

Comment: they are all definitely tables I just looked to verify. In the design table I see a table name Table_check, Table_timecard

Comment: Try the formula I put. You'll need to drag it down

Comment: Trying it now, what's the [#data] part of Table_check[#data] supposed to be?

Comment: @David all non-headers in the table.

Comment: ah ok, i get an error message saying the is an error in the formula.

Comment: Get rid of the `@`. New formula above

Comment: I get the same error saying there is an error in the formula

Comment: The structure of the formula works for me with my data, you haven't provided a great detail of your data. If they are on separate sheets, you'll need to indicate that in the formula.

Comment: i apologize new to this. Timecard sheet has Table_timecard and Check sheet has Table_check and i'm trying to get my results on the Report sheet that also has a table called Table_report